# why does foreach skip 2 rows from the query result?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

For 10 rows in the query it only returns 8 rows but i get the fields right:

For Query data which returns less than 2 rows I get an error.

```
//create table to display all data
echo "<table border="1"> ";
echo "<tr>";
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    foreach($row as $key => $value) 
        {
            echo "<th>$key</th>";
        }
echo "</tr>";

while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) !== null) 
{
  $output = array();
  $i=1;

  echo "<tr>";

    foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) 
        {
            $output[] = $columnName."=>". $columnValue;
            echo "<td>".$columnValue."</td>";
        }

  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Please post the `foreach` in its correct context of your fetch loop.  I suspect there's something going on like calling `mysqli_fetch_row()` both inside and outside a loop, causing a row to be skipped since the result resource isn't rewound.

Comment: here is my query for 1 row of $result. I get no output.
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 if (is_array($row))
 {
 echo "Yes, this is an array<br>";
 foreach($row as $key => $value) 
  {
   echo"$key\n";
  }
 }

Comment: the "invalid argument supplied for foreach()" part is probably due to not checking for `mysqli_fetch_row()` result against `false` which is returned instead of an array if there are no more rows to fetch

Comment: Do you mean to say that it skips the first two _columns_ and only returns 8 _columns_ ?  The difference is significant from _rows_.

Comment: Adding my modified code in the original question where I am creating a table with 10 rows on data it only returns 8

Comment: what is query when you  getting 8 row instated of 10 row???please check  your query

Comment: As suspected in my first comment.  Every time you call `mysqli_fetch_*()` the result resource is advanced by one row. You call it once before the first `foreach` so the resource has already skipped one row. You are checking `!== null`, but the function will return `false` instead of `null`. The type-safe `!==` is not met, so the loop body is entered.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, but wouldn't that explanation predict 9 rows out of 10 to be displayed?

Comment: @CEP Yes, but we don't see the full code either. It could very well be that an even earlier fetch call was made after the query.

Comment: @KumarGavade Please add still more code - where you initially call `mysqli_query()` and its surrounding code

Comment: Agreed. And how does the loop terminate, given that `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns `false` and not `null` when it fails (edit: _when there is no row fetched_)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, CEP Perfect. So i removed all the earlier calls and now I get 10 rows!! Thanks a lot. I still dont know how would i seperately create a table header without using two foreach loops.

Comment: @KumarGavade This is something complicated by the fact that you're trying to fetch rows and output them at the same time. I would suggest doing one `while` loop to load an array `$rows` with something like `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$rows[] = $row;}`.  Then you can get the columns to make a header just from `$rows[0]` and later do a  `foreach` over the entire `$rows` array.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sounds good. Let me give it a try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Thanks to @Michael Berkowski for his comments on the question.

---

Here is a modified version of your code that should work:

```
//create table to display all data
echo "<table border=1 >";
echo "<tr>";
//echo "<th> ## </th>";

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  // stick to the object-oriented form. It is cleaner.
foreach ($row as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "<th>$key</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

do
{
    $output = array();
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) 
    {
        $output[$columnName] = $columnValue;  // this is neater.
        echo "<td>" . $columnValue . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
} while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());

echo "</table>";
```

You can use your first `foreach()` loop to print the `key`s and then use a `do-while()` loop to get your desired output.

**Additional reading:**

- [PHP do-while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: Are you kidding me? 2 upvotes? The OP isn't even using `mysql_*()`.

Comment: It's now the correct API, but still not especially helpful. `mysqli_fetch_row()` returns a numeric indexed array and no matter which is used, the `foreach` should still return the correct number of columns (though the displayed output from `echo "$key\n";` is less useful)

Comment: its not the columns but the number of rows that its skipping. The first two always. Please see the new code updated in the question